# How to get the installation event without using Bot SDK?

Tags: microsoft-teams-js

I need to receive an event indicating that the Tab Application has been installed by the user. Yes, I know that such an event can be obtained if using the Bot SDK, but are there any other options? Because adding a bot to the application just for one event is too much.Thank you.

So far, I've found information about webhooks, but it's not clear yet how to work with them and whether they will be suitable in my case.